# Qual a diferença entre os operadores de comparação no Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, pl-sql

No Oracle existem vários operadores para fazer comparações de "diferente", como:

```
<>
¬=
!=
^=
```

Exemplo:

```
Select * from tabel where nomeTabela <> 's';
Select * from tabel where nomeTabela != 's';
Select * from tabel where nomeTabela ^= 's';
Select * from tabel where nomeTabela ¬= 's';
```

Todos irão retornar o mesmo resultado, dito isso gostaria de saber se existe alguma diferença de performance, versão entre eles? Caso não, existe previsão de descontinuidade para algum deles?

Comment: Isso não é só no `Oracle`, pelo menos alguns desses operadores também funcionam da mesma forma no `MySQL`, então imagino que seja algo do próprio `SQL`.

Comment: Não sabia, tenho vivido mais no oracle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dando uma lida na [documentação](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/conditions002.htm#SQLRF52107), todos esses operadores fazem a mesma coisa. Não há diferença entre perfomance e ou ordem de execução.

A imagem a seguir mostra a ordem de execução, que aparenta ser a mesma para todos operadores de condição:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Se pesquisar mais sobre o assunto, verá que para o SQL no geral, independente do SGBD, é favorecido o uso do `<>` como o padrão na comparação de desigualdades.

Comment: Faltou o `¬=` na figura.

Comment: Verdade, engraçado que a imagem foi retirada da documentação oficial.

Comment: @BrunoCosta Provavelmente quem bolou a imagem esqueceu isso.

Comment: Pelo que conferi nas outras respostas operador ¬= é o mais antigo e menos utilizado.

Answer (score 4):

Só achei informação indicando que nem todos funcionam em todas as plataformas.

Não há documentação de diferenças em nada, portanto trate eles como sendo idênticos. Mesmo que eventualmente possam ter performance diferentes, e não vejo razão para isto, nada garante que será sempre assim. Nem faria sentido serem diferentes. E não podem mudar o comportamento que já está documentado.

De fato [alguém fez o teste e notou que dá o mesmo resultado](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12512894/221800). Houve quem contestou.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 2):

De acordo com [**essa página da oracle**](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A87860_01/doc/server.817/a85397/operator.htm#1016204), na tabela 3-4 dessa página:

> `!=`
>   `^=`
>   `<   >`
>   `¬=`
>
> Inequality test. Some forms of the inequality operator may be unavailable on some platforms.

Traduzindo:

> Teste de desigualdade. Algumas formas do operador de desigualdade podem não estar disponíveis em algumas plataformas.

Acredito que o caso do `<   >` deveria ser `<>`. Não são o maior-que (`>`) e o menor-que (`<`) que são descritos logo abaixo na tabela.

Ou seja, todos eles são equivalentes.

A SQL no Oracle é compilada para uma forma interna de árvore. Isso significa que não há diferença de desempenho mensurável entre eles.

Answer (score 2):

*Esses operadores "não iguais" devem ser equivalentes, mas existe uma nota de Scott Canaan que sugere, no Oracle 10.2, eles podem produzir diferentes planos de execução e, portanto, diferentes velocidades de execução:*

```
Select count(*) from claws_doc_table where claws_doc_id = :id and exists
(select 1 from claws_person_id where status != 0);
```

*Se você usar `!=`, Ele retorna em um sub-segundo. Se você usar `<>`, são necessários 7 segundos para retornar. Ambos retornam a resposta certa.*

Acredito que a velocidade seria mais avariada pelo tamanho e formato das consultas do que propriamente pelos sinais usados, mas claro que deveria ser testado de forma individual cada consulta. 
Se quiser testar algumas no seu projeto, recomendo:

[SQL Performance Analyzer](https://oracle-base.com/articles/11g/sql-performance-analyzer-11gr1)

> [Nota de Scott Canaan](https://www.freelists.org/post/oracle-l/Performance-Difference-Between-and)

Answer (score 2):

Não há nenhuma diferença em questão de performance apenas a sintaxe que é diferente. Mas caso deseje fazer uma query compatível o padrão SQL, utilize o operador "<>" que é aceito também em outras plataformas.
Sobre a descontinuidade dos operadores, todas constam atualmente na documentação oficial da Oracle.